# Animate image view inside a container view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to animate a image view inside a container view. 
Container view is square and aligned center of the screen. i do have a image view inside my container. position of my image view is shown in below screenshot.(super view is my container view)

[image]

i want to animate the image view inside the container like from top 0 to bottom 0 so i tried animating from top 0 to top maximum (that is height of the container view) but it is not working as expected. My expected output is something like  the image view should animate inside container view continuously from top to bottom and reverse.

animation method which i tried is

```
int maxTop = self.containerView.frame.size.height/2;
self.topConstraint.constant = maxTop;
[self.imageView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    [self.imageView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
```

EDIT:
Here is the current output GIF. It is not moving to full height
[image: GIF]

Comment: my top space of image view is 0. image is not correct

Comment: Maybe you need to call layoutIfNeeded for self, not the imageView? Because imageView is a subView of self (containerView) and layoutIfNeeded works with subviews only.
Plus, you can add both top(0) and bottom(0) constraint with a different priorities and animate the constraint priorities, not the constants.

Comment: @Sega-Zero that makes sense. Let me try your suggested way

Comment: @Sega-Zero unfortunately that is not working as expected. I tried layoutIfNeeded to the container view :(

Comment: does height constraint set for imageView? I've made a [sample project](http://www.filedropper.com/sampleproject) and your code is working as expected.

Comment: @Sega-Zero now it is working (kind of) but the image view width is changing during animations. I knew this might be the problem with my constraints. Anyway i have shared the code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv6d4dsripuddug/sample%20project%202.zip?dl=0)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your constraints. You just need to start the animation in viewDidAppear, so the parent view could align itself properly before animation will start.

Comment: @Sega-Zero that works as expected. Please post your suggestion as answer for future readers also ill accept that as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation should be started after viewDidAppear, so the parent view could align itself properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil;
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[self.topConstraint.animator setConstant:maxTop];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

As in your original code you didn't set the constraint's constant inside the animation

Comment: AFAIK once you called LayoutIfNeeded...all the changes which we did for constraints will happen. No need to have the constraint change inside animation block..